# User is not defined in Node.js Express controller function

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, mongoose-schema

When I click reset password button it throws user is not defined in the command prompt for back-end. I am using Mongoose with Node.js Express. Here is the code for both model and controller.

**controller**

```
const User = require('../models/userModels');
const passwordResetToken = require('../models/resettokenModels');

async ResetPassword(req, res) {
    if (!req.body.email) {
      return res
        .status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
        .json({ message: 'Email is required' });
    }

    const userEmail = await User.findOne({
      email: Helpers.lowerCase(req.body.email)
    });
    if (!userEmail) {
      return res
        .status(HttpStatus.CONFLICT)
        .json({ message: 'Email does not exist' });
    }

            var resettoken = new passwordResetToken({ _userId: user._id, resettoken: crypto.randomBytes(16).toString('hex') });
            resettoken.save(function (err) {
                if (err) { return res.status(500).send({ msg: err.message }); }
                var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
                    service: '"SendGrid"',
                    auth:
                     {
                      user: 'email',
                      pass: 'password'
                     }
                });
                var mailOptions = {
                    from: 'email',
                    subject: 'Node.js Password Reset',
                    text: 'You are receiving this because you (or someone else) have requested the reset of the password for your account.\n\n' +
                      'Please click on the following link, or paste this into your browser to complete the process:\n\n' +
                      'http://' + req.headers.host + '/reset/' + resettoken + '\n\n' +
                      'If you did not request this, please ignore this email and your password will remain unchanged.\n'
                }

                transporter.sendMail(mailOptions 
                )          
            })

        .catch(err => {
            res
                .status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
                .json({ message: 'Error occured' });
        });
    },
```

And here is the model

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');
const resettokenSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    _userId: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, required: true, ref: 'User' },
    resettoken: { type: String, required: true },
    createdAt: { type: Date, required: true, default: Date.now, expires: 43200 },
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('passwordResetToken', resettokenSchema);
```

USer model

```
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  username: { type: String },
  email: { type: String },
  password: { type: String },
  ...
 ...
```

Error is showing in this line inside controller

```
 var resettoken = new passwordResetToken({ _userId: user._id, resettoken: crypto.randomBytes(16).toString('hex') });
```

What can cause such an issue?

Comment: I don't see a `user` object, I see a `userEmail` object though...

Comment: I can import User model as well if it's needed here. In the project it exists in both controller imports and as a model.

Comment: think you're missing the hint here, you need to rename `user._id` to `userEmail._id`

Comment: Not it throws can't read property of catch in this line:
 .catch(err => {
            res
                .status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
                .json({ message: 'Error occured' });

it's the last block of controller,

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in comments you are not setting user to anything.

edit:

This is using your user schema, you have shown above that the user schema has username, email, password, ect.

```js
const user = await User.findOne({
      email: Helpers.lowerCase(req.body.email)
    });
```

Your reset token needs to do this:

```js
var resettoken = new passwordResetToken({ _userId: user._id, resettoken: crypto.randomBytes(16).toString('hex') });
```

Your nodemailer needs to do this:

```js
var mailOptions = {
  from: 'mail@mail.com',
  to: user.email,
  subject: 'Node.js Password Reset',
  text: 'some message'
}

transporter.sendMail(mailOptions)
```

Comment: It doesn't solve the problem. After that I removed last catch block even after that it throws another error.

Comment: I've added this line in email options too. to: userEmail,
It throws can't send mail all recipients are rejected.

Comment: what is userEmail. Looking at your code that's not the email, thats the user object. Perhaps consider renaming your variable userEmail to user. Because I think you're trying to do user.email - based on your schema.

Comment: in user schema it's just email.

Comment: i've edited my response to better answer and outline what I think is wrong with your current implementation. To be clear, in your code sample above, the user schema is not just email.

Comment: Thanks for improving it. It's sending email now. But something strange is happening inside email. It looks like this. You are receiving this because you (or someone else) have requested the reset of the password for your account.

Please click on the following link, or paste this into your browser to complete the process:

http://localhost:3000/reset/{ _id: 5c520203f619fa3338b21b11,

_userId: 5c4b27071478961b201e459d,
resettoken: 'be07e2aa043a2ced5b8574bca52c5afb',
createdAt: 2019-01-30T19:58:59.083Z,
__v: 0 }
If you did not request this ...

Comment: URL is not complete also it shows user id token and created at inside email body with other strange datas while only should contain text and URL with reset token.

Comment: This is again coming down to an understanding of how to reference a document schema with mongoose. 

`resettoken` is an object, not a singular value, in your case you want to do something like this:

`req.headers.host + '/reset/' + resettoken.resettoken`

Please do some research into working with and referencing documents with mongoose. If you have additional problems I would recommend opening a new question as you are expanding the scope of the current question.

I'd recommend considering storing the token on the user object rather than managing another document just for this.